# why adding string to NSMutableArray not work?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

why adding string to nsmuarray not work?
firstly, i add the a NSDictionary by keypath to the NSMutableArray, 
its work.
after that i want to add one more string to that but its not work.

```
NSMutableArray *_joinornot;

_joinornot = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSDictionary *tempobject = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

_joinornot = [tempobject valueForKeyPath:@"groupid"];
```

until now everything work.

```
[_joinornot addObject:@"111"];<----unrecongnized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: Where did you actually allocate an NSMutableArray and add it to the dictionary?

Comment: i have initialize the NSMutableArray

Comment: [_joinornot addObject:@"111"];   just this line is not work..

Comment: what's error you got?

Comment: unrecongnized selector sent to instance

Comment: that means `_joinornot` has somehow become not an `NSMutableArray` you will need to be careful on what you put in `[tempobject valueForKeyPath:@"groupid"];` maybe its returning a normal `NSArray`

Comment: what if it is a normal array,  can i add a string to it?   sorrty about that i am new to objc

Comment: NSArray is not mutable, which means it cant be changed, therefore you cant add to it, hence why we have an NSMutableArray

Comment: how can i make it become mutable?

Comment: how can i add the value for key but i will still a NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `_joinornot = [tempobject valueForKeyPath:@"groupid"];` returns nil, then your array will be nil, and then you cant call addObject. so maybe add a nil check

Comment: i have check that its not nil before addobject

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

Before adding object just check for `nil`.

```
NSMutableArray *_joinornot;

    _joinornot = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *tempobject = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

    _joinornot = [tempobject valueForKeyPath:@"groupid"];

    if (_joinornot==nil) {

        _joinornot = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [_joinornot addObject:@"111"];
    }
    else{

        [_joinornot addObject:@"111"];
    }
```

Edit:

May be it's converted to NSArray so it will be no more mutable, try with

```
_joinornot = [[tempobject valueForKeyPath:@"groupid"] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "_joinornot" it's not an NSMutableArray or NSMutable data type, try to see what kind of object it is:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [_joinornot class]);
```

If it is not a subclass of Mutable type you can't add objects to him.

Comment: If you want to add the string maybe this help: _joinornot = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: _joinornot]; just before add the string